# Перенаправление с site.ru/x.html на site.ru/blog/x.html

Tags: html, редирект

Привет!

Раньше страницы блога шли сразу после site.ru, т.е.
site.ru/post1.html ; 
site.ru/post2.html
...

Теперь новые ссылки доступны по ссылкам site.ru/blog/post1.html и так далее

Как прописать редирект для такого в htacess?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^post(.+)/$ /blog/post$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, это будет перенаправлять все страницы, верно?

Проблема в том, что помимо страниц блога есть еще и обычные ( О нас, история и тому подобное ).

Comment: Немного поправил правило. Должно работать если у вас все старницы постов выглядели как  site.ru/postX

Comment: А если самостоятельно прописать адреса? Их там 8 штук.

Comment: Или разумнее будет в Cpanel, к примеру, настроить редиректы? 

Просто посты названы по разному :/